# Missing info on high level stack frames using gdb with pygdbmi

Tags: python-3.x, gdb, fuzzing

I am trying to automate the task of finding out which line of code caused a crash. I have an output from AFL which will make a simple vulnerable program crash, and I would like to run it with GDB to find the crashing line, through a script.

I am using [pygdbmi](https://github.com/cs01/pygdbmi) which is based on the GDB/MI interface.
I am able to start the application with the crashing input and visualize part of the stack trace but not the last few frames (including the place in the source code of the application where it crashed).
I can however easily get all the stack trace if I run gdb normally from the command line.

What I get with normal GDB (which includes frame #5 in main.c):

```
(gdb) r < out_inputs/crashes/id:000000,sig:06,src:000003,op:havoc,rep:16
Starting program: ~/projects/project_fuzz/afl-training/quickstart/vulnerable < out_inputs/crashes/id:000000,sig:06,src:000003,op:havoc,rep:16
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff7a24801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff7a6d897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, 
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b9a988 "*** %s ***: %s terminated\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff7b18cd1 in __GI___fortify_fail_abort (need_backtrace=need_backtrace@entry=false, 
    msg=msg@entry=0x7ffff7b9a966 "stack smashing detected") at fortify_fail.c:33


#4  0x00007ffff7b18c92 in __stack_chk_fail () at stack_chk_fail.c:29
#5  0x00000000004011a1 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at vulnerable.c:44
(gdb)
```

What I get with pygdbmi (where I can't get info about frame #5):

```
writing: backtrace
{'message': None, 'payload': 'backtrace\\n', 'stream': 'stdout', 'type': 'log'}
{'message': None,
 'payload': '#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at '
            '../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51\\n',
 'stream': 'stdout',
 'type': 'console'}
{'message': None,
 'payload': '#1  0x00007ffff7a24801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79\\n',
 'stream': 'stdout',
 'type': 'console'}
{'message': None,
 'payload': '#2  0x00007ffff7a6d897 in __libc_message '
            '(action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b9a988 '
            '\\"*** %s ***: %s terminated\\\\n\\") at '
            '../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181\\n',
 'stream': 'stdout',
 'type': 'console'}
{'message': None,
 'payload': '#3  0x00007ffff7b18cd1 in __GI___fortify_fail_abort '
            '(need_backtrace=need_backtrace@entry=false, '
            'msg=msg@entry=0x7ffff7b9a966 \\"stack smashing detected\\") at '
            'fortify_fail.c:33\\n',
 'stream': 'stdout',
 'type': 'console'}
{'message': None,
 'payload': '#4  0x00007ffff7b18c92 in __stack_chk_fail () at '
            'stack_chk_fail.c:29\\n',
 'stream': 'stdout',
 'type': 'console'}
{'message': None,
 'payload': '#5  0x00000000004011a1 in ?? ()\\n',
 'stream': 'stdout',
 'type': 'console'}
{'message': None,
 'payload': '#6  0x64436d7364616568 in ?? ()\\n',
 'stream': 'stdout',
 'type': 'console'}
{'message': None,
 'payload': '#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()\\n',
 'stream': 'stdout',
 'type': 'console'}
{'message': 'done',
 'payload': None,
 'stream': 'stdout',
 'token': None,
 'type': 'result'}
[{'message': None,
  'payload': 'backtrace\\n',
  'stream': 'stdout',
  'type': 'log'},
 {'message': None,
  'payload': '#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at '
             '../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51\\n',
  'stream': 'stdout',
  'type': 'console'},
 {'message': None,
  'payload': '#1  0x00007ffff7a24801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79\\n',
  'stream': 'stdout',
  'type': 'console'},
 {'message': None,
  'payload': '#2  0x00007ffff7a6d897 in __libc_message '
             '(action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b9a988 '
             '\\"*** %s ***: %s terminated\\\\n\\") at '
             '../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181\\n',
  'stream': 'stdout',
  'type': 'console'},
 {'message': None,
  'payload': '#3  0x00007ffff7b18cd1 in __GI___fortify_fail_abort '
             '(need_backtrace=need_backtrace@entry=false, '
             'msg=msg@entry=0x7ffff7b9a966 \\"stack smashing detected\\") at '
             'fortify_fail.c:33\\n',
  'stream': 'stdout',
  'type': 'console'},
 {'message': None,
  'payload': '#4  0x00007ffff7b18c92 in __stack_chk_fail () at '
             'stack_chk_fail.c:29\\n',
  'stream': 'stdout',
  'type': 'console'},
 {'message': None,
  'payload': '#5  0x00000000004011a1 in ?? ()\\n',
  'stream': 'stdout',
  'type': 'console'},
 {'message': None,
  'payload': '#6  0x64436d7364616568 in ?? ()\\n',
  'stream': 'stdout',
  'type': 'console'},
 {'message': None,
  'payload': '#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()\\n',
  'stream': 'stdout',
  'type': 'console'},
 {'message': 'done',
  'payload': None,
  'stream': 'stdout',
  'token': None,
  'type': 'result'}]
```

My very simple python script:

```
from pygdbmi.gdbcontroller import GdbController
from pprint import pprint

gdbmi = GdbController()
print(gdbmi.get_subprocess_cmd())

gdbmi.write('-file-exec-file ./vulnerable')

gdbmi.write('-exec-arguments < ~/projects/project_fuzz/afl-training/quickstart/out_inputs/crashes/id:000000,sig:06,src:000003,op:havoc,rep:16')

gdbmi.write('show args')

gdbmi.write('-exec-run')

response = gdbmi.write('backtrace', verbose=True)
pprint(response)
```